# unexpected result on recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I followed the path of the whole execution and according my calculations it should be return 24, but in fact it returns 7

```js
function factorial(x) {
    if (x < 0) return;
    if (x === 0) return 1;
    return x + 1 * factorial(x - 1);
  }

let x = factorial(3);

console.log(x); //7
```

I´m likely not understand properly the recursive functions

Comment: Shouldn't 3! return 6?

Comment: I think you mean `(x + 1) * factorial(x - 1)`. Multiplication has a higher order of precedence so in your case the expression would work as if `x + (1 * factorial(x - 1))`

Comment: Wait, now that I think about it - why do you actually do `x + 1`? The definition of a factorial is just `n * (n - 1) * ... * (n - (n -1))` - you shouldn't be adding anything.

Comment: has anyone actually ran the function? It returns `2` then twice `NaN`

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, I forgot the parenthesis I meant:  (x + 1) * factorial(x - 1) In that case it returns 10 which is ok. Sorry my mistake

Comment: @Jmainol if you are trying to implement the factorial function this is not the correct result... take a look at my answer

Comment: @ZombieChowder not sure what you mean. This one returns `7`.

Comment: Yes, that´s right 7. It was just a question of the parenthesis. Thanks for your help @VLAZ I´m quite new using this. Could you tell me how can I highlight the code on this comments?

Comment: @Jmainol just put backticks (usually Shift + tilde - the key under Esc) around it: \`code\` produces `code`.

Comment: Ok, like the simbol use for literal strings. Code: `let x = x * 2` Just trying thanks

Answer (score 3):

You seem to understand the basics of recursive programming quite well, however I'm not sure you fully understand how the factorial function works.

For example:

3! = 3*2*1 = 6

4! = 4*3*2*1 = 24

You could express this in a recursive way :

a(0) = 1

a(n) = a(n - 1) * n

Implementing this logic in your code you would get the following :

```js
function factorial(x) {
  if (x < 0) return;
  if (x === 0) return 1;
  return x * factorial(x - 1);
}

console.log(factorial(4))
```

Which returns 24 as expected.

Comment: @StephenDuffy there is an explanation for that, actually. `n!` can be represented as `((n+1)!) / (n+1)`, so `3!` would be `4! / 4`. It makes sense `4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1` and if you divide by `4` you're left with `3 * 2 * 1` which is `3!`. It's also a mutually recursive factorial definition which is fun. At any rate, if you look at `0!` that would be `1! / 1` which gives you `1`. There you go. Another way to explain it is permutations - `n!` is the number of ways to arrange `n` items. And with zero items there is exactly *one* arrangement - an empty one.

Comment: @StephenDuffy but probably the most accurate explanation for `0! = 1` is also very disappointing. It's as follows: because mathematicians defined it that way. As I said, disappointing. But mathematicians do tend to define things that don't make complete sense in other terms because it then helps out with solving some formulas. Apparently, the number `1` is not prime, because if it was, you'd make some equation that uses primes a lot harder. Hence why `1` is excluded.

Comment: @VLAZ: yes, because it's defined that way.  But its not arbitrary.  As you pointed out, they're defined that way because they are much more useful definitions, both the definition of `0!` and the definition of "prime number".  More difficult ones are things like `0 ^ 0`, which has several competing possibilities; yes there is a best one (`0 ^ 0 = 1`), and so it's often the accepted one, but there is another reasonable option (`0 ^ 0 = 0`), so it's much more ambiguous.